Integral Inequality for odd function
I want to show if $f : [-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ odd function then $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 (f(x))^2 dx\leq \int_{-1}^1 (f'(x))^2 dx$. My idea was to write if $F(x)=\int_{-1}^x f(t) dt$, then the left hand side is
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)^2 dx=f(x)F(x)|_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1 F(x)f'(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1 -F(x)f'(x)dx
\end{align*}
by oddness of $f$. But this does not lead me anywhere.

Both $f^2$ and $(f')^2$ are even, so the statement can be equivalently stated using $\int_0^1$ rather than $\int_{-1}^1$. From that perspective it's clear that the oddness of $f$ is a bit of a red herring, and you only need the fact that $f(0)=0$.

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is $C^1$, we have
$$f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt,\quad\forall\ x\in[0,1].$$
Then it follows from Cauchy–Schwarz inequality that
$$|f(x)|\leq \left(\int_0^xf'(t)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^x1\,dt\right)^{1/2}\leq x^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2},\quad\forall\ x\in[0,1].$$
Hence
$$\int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx\leq \int_0^1x\left(\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,dt\right)\,dx=\frac12\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,dt=\frac12\int_0^1f'(x)^2\,dx.$$
For the same reason one has
$$\int_{-1}^0f(x)^2\,dx\leq\frac12\int_{-1}^0f'(x)^2\,dx.$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{-1}^1f(x)^2\,dx\leq\frac12\int_{-1}^1f'(x)^2\,dx.$$
And the desired inequality in the OP follows from $\frac12<1$.
Remark.

We only use $f(0)=0$ and the fundamental theorem of calculus. So, it is not necessary to require the oddness of $f$.
Probably $\frac12$ is not the optimal constant. It seems that one can obtain the best constant by expanding $f$ in the form of Fourier series, which gives the constant $\frac4{\pi^2}$.

